# How to prove an equality of $(A\Delta B)\Delta C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B,C$ be sets and define
$$
A\Delta B := (A\cup B) \setminus (A \cap B).
$$
There are many posts that ask to prove the $\Delta$ is associative.

> However, I would like to show that $$ (A\Delta B)\Delta C = (A\cap B\cap C) ~\cup~ (A \setminus (B\cup C)) ~\cup~ (B\setminus (C\cup A)) ~\cup~ (C\setminus (A\cup B)). $$

I tried to use basic rearrangements to get to the result but failed because I lost track and was not able to simplify pretty much at the beginning.

Comment: Drawing a Venn diagram would probably be the easiest way forward. If drawing diagrams feels too childish, use a truth table instead -- but it's the same thing you would be doing.

Comment: @HenningMakholm How does a truth table help? A,B,C are sets...

Comment: @SimonMueller: Proving $X=Y$ for sets is the same thing as proving $x\in X\leftrightarrow x\in Y$ for arbitrary $x$, and for both sides of your equality $x\in\mathit{(set)}$ unfolds to some propositional combination of $x\in A$, $x\in B$ and $x\in C$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use the definition $A\Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$.

Throughout the post, $A\setminus B\setminus C=(A\setminus B)\setminus C$ and $A\setminus B\cap C=(A\setminus B)\cap C$. In general, absent parenthesis everything is evaluated left-to-right with the same priority. Recall the identities $A\setminus(B\cup C)=(A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C)=A\setminus B\setminus C$ and $A\setminus(B\setminus C)=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap C)$.

\begin{align}(A\Delta B)\Delta C&=(((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A))\setminus C)\cup(C\setminus((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)))=\\&=(A\setminus B\setminus C)\cup(B\setminus A\setminus C)\cup((C\setminus(A\setminus B))\cap (C\setminus(B\setminus A)))=\\&=(A\setminus B\setminus C)\cup(B\setminus A\setminus C)\cup\left(\left(\stackrel{1}{(C\setminus A)}\cup\stackrel{2}{(C\cap B)}\right)\cap\left(\stackrel{a}{(C\setminus B)}\cup\stackrel{b}{(C\cap A)}\right)\right)=\\&=(A\setminus B\setminus C)\cup(B\setminus A\setminus C)\cup\stackrel{1\cap a}{(C\setminus A\setminus B)}\cup\stackrel{1\cap b}\emptyset\cup\stackrel{2\cap a}\emptyset\cup\stackrel{2\cap b}{(C\cap B\cap A)}=\\&=(A\setminus B\setminus C)\cup(B\setminus C\setminus A)\cup(C\setminus A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B\cap C)\end{align}

QED.